# Retrieve current and localized month

Tags: date

instead of writing array of months in desired language, and doing a function to replace  date('m') with localized month... I believe there should be some fast and easy way to echo current month, after all its Wordpress?

I have define('WPLANG', 'hr');

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
global $wp_locale;
echo $wp_locale->get_month( date( 'm' ) );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to what your code does and how it works. Dumping code as an answer is not considered a very good answer. Please file an [edit] and add all relevant info